# pandas header does exist but still getting KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting a `Keyerror 'stackoverflow'` when I run my code.

```
e0 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"E0.txt",sep=',')
e0['MTM'] = e0['stack_over_flow']
```

I did output the columns of `e0` and I do get `stack_over_flow` in my columns.

```
b'Super_user'
b'Personal_finance'
b'stack_over_flow'
```

I also tried removing the `b` manually from the .txt file and still get the same error. Can anyone help with this?

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-74-99e71d524b4b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py', wdir='C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3')

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py", line 474, in <module>
    M2()

  File "C:/AppData/FinRecon/py_code/python3/DataJoin.py", line 41, in M2
    e0['MTM'] = e0['stack_over_flow']

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\stack\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\anaconda3_32bit\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'stack_over_flow'
```

Update, I figured it out it is the `b` and `''` before and between
 each header. Why does this get added to my .txt file?

Comment: [Provide a copy of the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe) or the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your data, something like below 
Say data for E0.txt is like below.

```
stackoverflow,"some column name", test
1, 2, 3
```

Use below code to retreive the content of any column.

```py
e0 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"E0.txt",sep=',')
e0['MTM'] = e0['stack_over_flow']
```

[image]

-- update --

without `b` I created a test sample, it works for below input

```
Super_user,Personal_finance,stack_over_flow
1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Im not sure what the change i have to make here. Are you just showing it is working for you?

Comment: you need to change the content of the file to UTF or something simple with 'b' in that.

Comment: tried this, `e0 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"E0.txt",sep=',',encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: why you need to use `b` in your text input. for me I remved all `b` then it worked.

Comment: I think in a prevous process it adds the `b`, Im not sure why this was done or what the purpose was. But I did remove the b's and still got the same issue.

Comment: ah i also removed the double quotes `''` between each column and it worked. However I am unsure why this is being added to my .txt files

Comment: how the file is generated ? Some programme is writing it? what language is used?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pandas dataframe is loaded, use the following method to select the columns,

```py
df[['stack_over_flow']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies in the encoding when reading the csv. Try adding `encoding='utf-8'` inside your `read_csv` call.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: same error after adding this,     `e0 = pd.read_csv(working_dir+"E0.txt",sep=',',encoding='utf-8')`